# Fetch data from MsSql Server through Php

Tags: php, sql-server

i am trying to fetch data from mssql server but when i run the code browser showw white blank screen. The connection & query are one in file, which is hosted on a normal website hosting.

```
$hostname = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbName = "dbname";

MSSQL_CONNECT($hostname,$username,$password) or DIE("DATABASE FAILED TO RESPOND.");
mssql_select_db($dbName) or DIE("Database unavailable");
```

Comment: `$con=MSSQL_CONNECT($hostname,$username,$password) or DIE("DATABASE FAILED TO RESPOND.");
mssql_select_db($dbName,$con) or DIE("Database unavailable");`

Comment: use a connection sting and pass to mssql_select_db()

Comment: still in the same state!

Comment: whats the error??

Comment: it's not even showing the error.

Comment: can u paste the full code

Comment: there nothing else i've written except a condition.   **if ($db_sl)
    {
    echo "DOne!";
    }**

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

if you want to check if the DB exists there are loads of resources online. try w3schools if this is new to you.

[mysqli_select_db() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp)

Comment: i am using mssql server and it's my sqli

Comment: Result:Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'servername' (110)

Comment: what are you using for your server name?

Comment: i am using domain name where data base is hosted

Comment: Have you tried the server IP , as the issue is not the statement/query

Answer (score 0):

```
$hostname = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbName = "dbname";

$conn = MYSQL_CONNECT($hostname,$username,$password) or DIE("DATABASE FAILED TO RESPOND.");
mysql_select_db($dbName) or DIE("Database unavailable");

$query = "select * from table";
$rs = mysql_query($query, $conn);
$rw = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
foreach($rw as $value){
echo $rw['col_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this Code

```
$servername="(server name)"; // use local if local server
$conn=new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername; database=dbname");
if($conn){

    //echo "success";
}
else{
    echo "error";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}
```